# fade in collection of thumbnails on UIScrollView one at a time

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have a large collection of thumbnails I display on a UIScrollView and I would like them to fade in nicely one at a time.  Right now they all fade in together after they are all loaded to the scrollview simply by hiding and showing the scrollview.  This is OK but it can take a long time for 500 images to be loaded.

I have tried several different variations of what I though would work by using background threads.

I thought this would work for sure but no luck.  I have a NSMutableArray of all of my UIImageViews that I have added to the scroll view, so once they are all in place and the scrollview is sized I call:

```
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(addThumbnailToScrollView) withObject:values];

    -(void) addThumbnailToScrollView: (NSDictionary *) aDictionary {

        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"Collection Item Count: %i, imageViewCount: %i", [self.collectionItems count],[self.imageViews count]);


            UIImage *img = [Helpers getThumbnailImage:[aDictionary valueForKey:@"PhotoName"] withManufacturer:manufacturerID];
            [(UIImageView*)[self.imageViews objectAtIndex:[[aDictionary valueForKey:@"i"] intValue]] setImage:img];   
            [(UIImageView*)[self.imageViews objectAtIndex:[[aDictionary valueForKey:@"i"] intValue]] setAlpha:0];   
            [UIView beginAnimations:@"fade" context:nil];
         [(UIImageView*)[self.imageViews objectAtIndex:[[aDictionary valueForKey:@"i"] intValue]] setAlpha:1];
            [UIView commitAnimations];


    [pool drain];
}
```

The UIView animation cause a crash because it is not done before the objects are released I guess.  Even when I remove the animation bit they image still pop onto the screen in large groups versus 1 by 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

-(void)animateTumbs:(NSInteger)index{
    index++;
    if ([self.imageViews count]

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                 animations:^{ 
                     [(UIImageView*)[self.imageViews objectAtIndex:[[aDictionary valueForKey:@"i"] intValue]] setAlpha:1];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){ 
                     [self animateTumbs:index];
                 }];
}
```

Or you can try:

[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(addThumbnailToScrollView) withObject:values afterDelay:0.2];

Good luck